Do I need downtime for adding new apigee OPDK datacenter region to existing datacenter region?
I have an existing apigee opdk datacenter. I would like to add another datacenter by following the instructions from this link https://docs.apigee.com/private-cloud/v4.52.02/adding-data-center . The existing datacenter has the users using the apigee API proxies. So, I need to know if there is downtime while I am adding new datacenter region.
Do we need downtime for existing datacenter's runtime while we adding a new apigee OPDK datacenter?

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

As per my understanding while adding a new Apigee OPDK data center, there should not be any downtime needed for your existing runtime. This is because Apigee OPDK allows multiple datacenters to work in parallelly. Each data center runs its own instances of the services, the load balancer distributes the traffic to each data center.
Each Apigee OPDK datacenter represents a separate environment. Your existing datacenter continues to operate independently.
And you are following Apigee’s adding a data center guidelines it is designed as without service interruption. Refer to this similar issue on googlecloudcommunity forum for more detail.
